# Adding custom attributes to a 3D model?

Tags: 3d, 3d-model

### Problem Statement

I would like to add additional data to a 3D model, without corrupting the file such that the model cannot be viewed in common 3D object viewers.

My desired output is a single file. This would allow a bespoke software package to pull out the additional data on demand, without preventing the user from inspecting the model in off-the-shelf viewers (the additional data is not required to be presented).

I have researched the topic and struggled to find a 3D file type which is capable of storing additional data... any ideas?

### Example "additional data"

I would like to assign two integers and one string to each **element** in the model:

- Lower Temperature (0-10000)
- Upper Temperature (0-10000)
- Well-known Name (string, 16 chars max)

I would also like to assign two strings to the entire model (i.e. the **file**):

- Model Identifier (string, 16 chars max)
- Job Reference (string, 16 chars max)

The data should live within in the file itself so it cannot be easily removed.

### Ideas

- I thought about having the additional data separate (a quick fix) but
  due to the large number of models, this would potentially lead to
  mismatched files. Hence the focus on *adding* data to the file, and
  not simply aligning an external data file.
- I have proven I could manipulate an .stl file to meet my needs... but
  this would deviate from the standard and thus corrupt the file for
  use in normal viewers.
- The "element" data may be repeated across many elements, so a lookup table
  within the file would reduce the amount of data needing to be stored in each element...
  but we'd need to find a place for the look-up table, and still assign an ID to each element.
- There must be a standard out there which allows for custom metadata for 3D objects?

Comment: If you are sure no other software should read this 3d model file, it is better to write your own serialiser / deserialiser. You can also write an exporter plugin in blender or other softwares to convert the file.

Comment: @codetiger - I am wanting the opposite. A well-known file format which can be opened in normal 3D viewers, but able to store additional data that I can take advantage of in my own deserialiser.

Comment: Collada file is a simple XML based and has everything you are asking.

Comment: Thanks @codetiger... why not make this an answer with a few reference links to help others out in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the exact use case for which Collada file format is designed for.

> COLLADA (COLLAborative Design Activity) is an interchange file format
> for interactive 3D applications. COLLADA defines an open standard XML
> schema for exchanging digital assets among various graphics software
> applications. COLLADA uses a .dae (digital asset exchange) as filename
> extension.

OpenCollada is an Open source SDK available for reading and writing a model file. The design allows us to add custom metadata as you are expecting. https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCOLLADA